# Apache beam multiple consumer groups in KafkaIO.read() | Out of memory

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm working on Apache Beam streaming. I've made a stream that reads a lot of topics and put all data in GCS.

My KafkaIO.reader is

```
KafkaIO.<String, AvroGenericRecord>read()
                .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers)
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(configUpdates)
                .withTopics(inputTopics)
                .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(BeamKafkaAvroGenericDeserializer.class, AvroGenericCoder.of(serDeConfig()))
                .withMaxNumRecords(maxNumRecords)
                .commitOffsetsInFinalize()
                .withoutMetadata();
```

In **configUpdates** I put *ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG* value.

I would like to make somehow that I could read 2-3 consumer groups, is it possible to achieve? Because I have some topics which data comes quickly and some of them are not.

**UPD**

The reason I wanted to make multiple consumer groups is Out of memory of my job.

```
gcp#3|Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
gcp#3|java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:184)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.processElements(ReduceFnRunner.java:368)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:94)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
gcp#3|        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
gcp#3|        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
gcp#3|        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
gcp#3|Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:34)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:218)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:180)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.processElements(ReduceFnRunner.java:368)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:94)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
gcp#3|        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
gcp#3|        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
gcp#3|        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
gcp#3|        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
gcp#3|Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

As I understand now the problem is not because of reading from Kafka it's because of incorrect windowing I think. I have a lot of topics (40+) and I try to read them all, a lot of data... I try to make **event time** windowing to handle everything.

This is my windowing:

```
 records.apply(Window.<AvroGenericRecord>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(options.getWindowInMinutes())))
                .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                        .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane())
                        .withLateFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(options.getElementsCountToWaitAfterWatermark())))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(1))
                .discardingFiredPanes()
```

**UPD 2.0**

I think it happens during writing.

This is my class which put avro data in GCP buckets. It should put data by topic name and timestamp. The final output should be **bucket/{topic}/{date}/{'avroContainerPerWindowOrPane'}**

This is how I did it.

```
public class DynamicAvroGenericRecordDestinations extends DynamicAvroDestinations<AvroGenericRecord, AvroDestination, GenericRecord> {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private final String baseDir;
    private final String fileExtension;

    public DynamicAvroGenericRecordDestinations(String baseDir, String fileExtension) {
        this.baseDir = baseDir;
        this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
    }

    @Override
    public Schema getSchema(AvroDestination destination) {
        return new Schema.Parser().parse(destination.jsonSchema);
    }

    @Override
    public GenericRecord formatRecord(AvroGenericRecord record) {
        return record.getRecord();
    }

    @Override
    public AvroDestination getDestination(AvroGenericRecord record) {
        Schema schema = record.getRecord().getSchema();
        return AvroDestination.of(record.getName(), record.getDate(), record.getVersionId(), schema.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public AvroDestination getDefaultDestination() {
        return new AvroDestination();
    }

    @Override
    public FileBasedSink.FilenamePolicy getFilenamePolicy(AvroDestination destination) {
        String pathStr = baseDir + "/" + destination.name + "/" + destination.date + "/" + destination.name;
        return new WindowedFilenamePolicy(FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible(pathStr), destination.version, fileExtension);
    }

    private static class WindowedFilenamePolicy extends FileBasedSink.FilenamePolicy {
        final ResourceId outputFilePrefix;
        final String fileExtension;
        final Integer version;

        WindowedFilenamePolicy(ResourceId outputFilePrefix, Integer version, String fileExtension) {
            this.outputFilePrefix = outputFilePrefix;
            this.version = version;
            this.fileExtension = fileExtension;
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceId windowedFilename(
                int shardNumber,
                int numShards,
                BoundedWindow window,
                PaneInfo paneInfo,
                FileBasedSink.OutputFileHints outputFileHints) {

            IntervalWindow intervalWindow = (IntervalWindow) window;

            String filenamePrefix =
                    outputFilePrefix.isDirectory() ? "" : firstNonNull(outputFilePrefix.getFilename(), "");

            String filename =
                    String.format("%s-%s(%s-%s)-(%s-of-%s)%s", filenamePrefix,
                            version,
                            formatter.print(intervalWindow.start()),
                            formatter.print(intervalWindow.end()),
                            shardNumber,
                            numShards - 1,
                            fileExtension);
            ResourceId result = outputFilePrefix.getCurrentDirectory();
            return result.resolve(filename, RESOLVE_FILE);
        }

        @Override
        public ResourceId unwindowedFilename(
                int shardNumber, int numShards, FileBasedSink.OutputFileHints outputFileHints) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Expecting windowed outputs only");
        }

        @Override
        public void populateDisplayData(DisplayData.Builder builder) {
            builder.add(
                    DisplayData.item("fileNamePrefix", outputFilePrefix.toString())
                            .withLabel("File Name Prefix"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello. Maybe you could try to send your question to user@beam.apache.org, where you might can answer from experts on Kafka IO.

Comment: @RuiWang thanks for the advice. I'm thinking about to make a simple foreach or just create 2 KafkaIO.read() but I'm not sure that it'll work

Comment: Hello @Dave, were you able to fix the issue? I can see that exception is thrown from `WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn` so probably the problem is not in Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `KafkaIO` allows to have different GROUP_IDs in the same Kafka read transform. Well, we allow two different consumer configs but this is because, under the hood, there are two consumers in `KafkaIO` actually - for messages and for offsets, so it's a different story. 
Btw, what is an issue to consume messages from the topics with different frequency of arriving in your case?

Comment: Honestly, I have a serious problem, it's Out of Memory that I have been trying to solve for 2 weeks already. I can't understand why I'm getting the OOM and I don't know because of what I get it. I'll update my issue if you have time, could you please look at the logs?

Comment: Yes, seems like that this issue is not related to KafkaIO. Could you explain what you want to accomplish with these triggers you posted above?
Btw, there is no error in `FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(options.getWindowInMinutes())`? You seem use minutes for Duration in hours

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change back Duration.standardHours -> Duration.standardMinutes. I want to make an event time stream that every 1 minute will output data. As it event time stream we have to pass a watermark, so let watermark be one day or one hour for an example.

Comment: If you still have OOM issue there then I'd recommend you to ask on Beam user@ mailing list (https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/) about that.